# RAM upgrade on a laptop that has modules of different size

Tags: memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade my laptop's RAM capacity. According to Dell's [specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-3501-laptop/inspiron-3501-setup-and-specifications/memory?guid=guid-e9d2ea83-38a4-431d-803c-96d63c1dbc34&lang=en-us&lwp=rt), the max capacity is 16GB, but I have seen upgrades of 32 GB without (apparent) trouble. I would be using 8GB + 16 GB (similar to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeServer/comments/ud2dvl/j5040itx_32_gb_ram_compatability/?rdt=35070)) , but I have read that using 2 modules of different sizes can result in a drop in speed. What confuses me is that my laptop *already* has two different size modules (4 GB and 8GB). Am I currently experiencing decreased performance (or how can I measure that) and will the 16 GB + 8GB be treated the same way as the 4 + 8?

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation on which ram to use?  Or are you looking for an assurance that what you have is fine?

Answer (score 1):

The decrease in performance is not very big for the CPU (usually around 5-10%). It is bigger for the IGP, that is for 3D graphics. So you are mostly affected when running games without a discrete GPU. The linked specs mention a GeForce MX330, but not if it is optional or always installed. If this GPU will be used for games, the performance decrease is not noticeable.